# Getting error "provisioning with enterprise failed" for good dynamic iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, blackberry, good-dynamics

I have configured Good dynamic SDK in iOS application. When I enter the account detail, App start fetching detail form Blackberry server. App getting error "provisioning with enterprise failed" while NOC Activation. Please check attached screenshot.

[image]
Please let us know if you have any solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the activation failure could be several 
1. The server is not running 
2. The connection to NOC is not established
3. Getting timed out due to poor connections
4. Network Firewall block the authentication

I have requested Apple Developer to try with different open network, which doesn't block any authentication call to Blackberry server.

They are able to test the application.

Problem solved!!!!